# How to use GitHub Package created from .dll (kendo)

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget-package, kendo-asp.net-mvc, github-packages

I'm using Kendo v2015.1.408.545 (file type .dll) as an standalone library for one of my project (on local)

I'm importing my project to Github and will be using Github CI/CD via Github runner for deployment

Now, I want to use Kendo library(dependency) as an package for my project
But the problem is Github doesn't allow a .dll to be added as a Github package

Alternate here is to create a dotnet project and add the .dll as an reference and create a nuget package from the .csproj and upload that nuget package on github and use

I've tried the above steps but I'm able to create the nuget package but when I try to use that nuget package instead of (original) .dll, I'm not able to import the library and use it in the project

Can someone please help me with an example ?

Comment: Try putting the DLL somewhere in the source folder (e.g. create a `DLLs` folder) and make your project(s) use it from there. If that works then put it in GitHub as well, by adding + committing + pushing it.

Comment: @PeterB What if I have multiple projects and I want to use the same Kendo dll everywhere ? 
Your approach will add duplication

Comment: @PeterB is there anything else that I can do ?

Comment: Sorry, I never created a NuGet package. It would seem the only option to avoid the duplication, at the same time I'm not sure it would be legal because you'd be putting someone else's DLL on a public feed. Certainly recommended to check the license.

Comment: I"ll be creating a private package using it for my private projects only (I guess then it won't be an issue as I bought it for standalone use)